# Google Chrome vs Firefox HTML/CSS structure

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, firefox

So I'm having this really odd and annoying problem with Firefox regarding a website.

If you take a look at this link: http://www.apollolive.com/?page_id=429

If you use Chrome while looking at it you can see that the images are displayed fine and text too, but when you check it in Firefox the images are gone and I have no idea why.

Internet Explorer is even worse. It displays all the images in a single vertical line to the bottom.

Can you tell me what is happening here ?

Comment: You shouldn't use the same `id` more than once! All your images have `id="allimg"`.

Comment: Yeah I noticed, will fix that thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't Know why are you using an `img` tag and setting a bakcground-image .... but anyway The problem with Firefox is `img` are inline by default then the setted dimensions has no effect on the element. Try adding `display`  property :

```
.sampleoverlay img {
   display:block;  
}
```

<sub>Also ID must be unique you have the same `#allimg` in all img change it to a classname</sub>

Now for IE works fine for me on IE8 and IE9 maybe you have yours in IE7 document mode, IE7 doesn't support `inline-block` you must use this to duplicate the same effect :

```
.sampleoverlay {
  display:inline-block;
  *display:inline;
  *zoom:1;
}
```

Also IE7 doesn't support `background-size`. I'm pretty sure the problem is the version of IE.

<sub>The `*` targets IE7</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much, that took care of the Firefox problem .. question is though what the hell is Explorer thinking .. - I'll mark your post as answer though and I'll take your word for changing those ID's .. it's a work in progress :) Thanks!

Comment: @SmáriAlfreðsson check the edit to see the solution for IE ... needs to be carefull about compatibility :)

Comment: Hey Danko, thanks for your suggesting, I am using IE 11 though and if I put these CSS styles like you said, then this will display even worse in Chrome and Firefox and not even change at all in Explorer! Strange thing..

Comment: But have you included the `*` is necessary ... @SmáriAlfreðsson

Comment: Haha .. no I didn't, it's pushing to the right direction now, thank you so much for walking me through this @Danko. Appreciate it!

Comment: @SmáriAlfreðsson jeje NP mate glad to help you